# Email script not working on IIS

Tags: perl, iis

I have the following test script to send an email:

```
use strict;
use Net::SMTP;

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
print "Sending email...\n";

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('10.0.0.1', Port => 25, Timeout => 10, Debug => 1);
$smtp->mail("user1\@domain.local");
$smtp->to("user2\@domain.local");
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("From: user1\@domain.local\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: user2\@domain.local\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: Test\n\n");
$smtp->datasend("Testing 1 2 3\n");
$smtp->datasend();
$smtp->quit;
```

It works fine when I run it from the command line, I get the email right away. But when I put it in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and run it from a web browser, I get the `Sending email...` text but then nothing. No email is sent, no error message is shown. I looked at the mail server log and no connection is even made. I'm not sure why it's working from cmd but not from IIS. Is there some extra configuration needed for the script to do this through IIS?

I also tried with `sendmail()` and get similar results.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add the following headers to the file

```
use strict 'vars';
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use feature qw/say/;
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

... your code...

# Print Warnings
warningsToBrowser(1);
```

That will give you more information if it's failing or throwing a warning on something.

Secondly, how did you install Net::SMTP? Make sure it, and all it's dependancies have permissions by the IIS worker process.

Comment: The error I get with the code you provided is `Can't call method &quot;mail&quot; on an undefined value at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.pl line 14.` which is what I would expect if the `Net::SMTP->new` call fails. But it still doesn't tell me why it failed. As for permissions in the worker process, I'm not sure what you mean. It's a simple Perl script in a default IIS installation so where would I look for that?

Comment: Have a look at running perl on IIS @ http://blogs.iis.net/wadeh/archive/2009/04/13/running-perl-on-iis-7.aspx

Comment: If thats too complicated, you can download the source for Net::SMTP from http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-3.04/lib/Net/SMTP.pm - copy the bin folder relative to your CGI, and add the library location using `use File::Basename; use lib dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/bin';`

Comment: I managed to get it to work when I changed the vdir credentials to a user with Administrators group privileges. I'm not sure if that's what did it, or why it was failing with no other details before as IUSR.

Comment: It seems like the module, or one of it's dependancies was installed without the correct credentials and is installed without the required permissions for IUSR.

Comment: It's a default IIS installation so I'm not sure how that would be. The CGI is a simple Perl script (also tried a CGI-EXE).